# How do I escape characters in Elasticsearch URI Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get my head around Elasticsearch and I keep running into issues, things I don't really get, which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere...

My document contains a name, lets say I can query it using `_search?q=doc.name:Name`

No what if the name has a space "Name Lastname", how do I query for that? I have tried many different ways but none of them seem to work.

Is obviously not as easy as `_search?q=doc.name:Name Lastname`
... that will query for Name and Lastname but not necessarily in that particular order.

Comment: Have you tried double quotes: `_search?q=doc.name:"Name Lastname"` ??

Comment: Hmmm, I did try it before. And it didn't work and that's why was so confused. But now it do work so I have to figure out what the hell happened. Thanks!